# fail2ban: unban behavior when two jails ban the same IP?

Tags: fail2ban

I have two `fail2ban` jails that deal with `postfix`: one called `postfixsasl` and one called `postfixauth`. They each are looking for different regex matches for triggering bans. It is possible that both of them might be triggered by activity from the same IP address, and that occurs sometimes.

If one of the bans expires before the other one, it seems like the IP address is getting unbanned, even though the second ban is still active.

For example, suppose I run `fail2ban-client get postfixauth banip --with-time` and I get the the following line within its output (actual IP address dummied out):

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd     2020-09-28 10:58:24 + 86400 = 2020-09-29 10:58:24
```

... and suppose I run `fail2ban-client get postfixsasl banip --with-time` and I get the following output. The same IP address is dummied out in the same way:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd     2020-09-28 20:00:37 + 3600 = 2020-09-28 21:00:37
```

Obviously, the second ban will expire before the first one will. However, it seems like once the second item gets unbanned, the `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` IP address seems to be unbanned, even before the first item's expiration time.

I want the `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` IP address to remain blocked until the latest ban expires, but this is not occurring for me.

Before 21:00:37 on 2020-09-29, the following line appears in the `f2b-postfixauth` section of `iptables -L` output:

```
REJECT     all  --  aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd         anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

... and the following line appears in the `f2b-postfixsasl` section of the `iptables -L` output:

```
REJECT     all  --  aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd         anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

After 21:00:37 on 2020-09-29, both lines are gone from the `iptables -L` output.

Is this expected behavior? Or could it be that there might be something totally unrelated that's wrong with my `fail2ban` configuration which causes this to occur? If this is not the expected behavior, then I will investigate my `fail2ban` configuration further.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `csf` for "normal", non-`fail2ban` firewall processing, and I figured out that `csf` and `fail2ban` interact with `iptables` in incompatible ways, and this is the cause of my problem.

I was using `iptables-multiport` within `fail2ban` in order to do the banning, and the simultaneous presence of `csf` as my firewall service caused previously banned (via `fail2ban`) IP addresses to still get through the firewall.

Instead of using `iptables-multiport`, I changed my `fail2ban` jail configuration to do its banning and unbanning solely via `csf`, as described here:
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2340

With `iptables-multiport` actions no longer being executed within my `csf`-enabled `fail2ban` setup, all banning and unbanning attempts are now working as expected.